# Button below listView

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to Android, and the first project I am working on is putting players onto a team. I have a listview that grabs all of the players from a database. Each name is supposed to have a checkbox next to them and then there is a button at the bottom that is supposed to update the database. So far this is what I am getting.

http://dyp.im/W79JdmfIk

Here is my activity

```
 package com.example.sqllitetest;

 import android.app.AlertDialog;
 import android.app.ListActivity;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.DialogInterface;
 import android.database.Cursor;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v4.widget.ResourceCursorAdapter;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.*;

public class Tester extends ListActivity {

MyAdapter mListAdapter;
PlayersDBAdapter mDbHelper;
private Button button;
private Context context = this;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDbHelper = new PlayersDBAdapter(this);
    mDbHelper.open();
    Cursor myCur = mDbHelper.fetchAllPlayers();
    startManagingCursor(myCur);
    setContentView(R.layout.playertoteam);

   // registerForContextMenu(getListView());
   // ((Tester) context).setContentView(R.layout.playertoteam);
    //getListView().addFooterView(button);
    mListAdapter = new MyAdapter(Tester.this, myCur);
    setListAdapter((ListAdapter) mListAdapter);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.alertBox);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            setResult(RESULT_OK);
            finish();
        }

    });

}


private class MyAdapter extends ResourceCursorAdapter {

    public MyAdapter(Context context, Cursor cur) {
        super(context, R.layout.playertoteam, cur);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cur, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        return li.inflate(R.layout.playertoteam, parent, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cur) {
        TextView tvListText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.code);
        CheckBox cbListCheck = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

        tvListText.setText(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(mDbHelper.KEY_NAME)));
        cbListCheck.setChecked((cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(mDbHelper.KEY_ID))==1? false:true));
    }




}
}
```

And here is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="6dip" >

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/alertBox"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/confirm" />
  <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="top" >
            <ListView
                android:id="@android:id/list"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@id/alertBox"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/code"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />

              <CheckBox android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"

                />

  </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I would like to know how to remove the buttons from the rows and the check box that is underneath the main confirm button. Also I would like to know if this is the best way to do something like this, because, once again, I am new and I don't know how to search for the correct methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ResourceCursorAdapter creates views ,for every row of the ListView, that are inflated in newView() method. You are getting button in every row because of this reason.
Soln: Create a separate xml defining the row layout for the ListView and inflate this new layout in the newView() method. And have only the button and ListView in main layout i.e. playertoteam.xml

playertoteam.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="6dip" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/alertBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="@string/confirm" />

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_above="@id/alertBox" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

row_layout.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/code"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

  <CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false" 
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

You can find example for ListView [here](https://github.com/asnehal/ListViewExample.git)

Comment: Thank you, this worked after I changed the Layout inflater to li.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false), instead of li.inflate(R.layout.playertoteam, parent, false). You are a gentleman and a scholar.

Answer (score 0):

you can use addFooterView method of listview.

```
View footerView =
((LayoutInflater)
ActivityContext.
getSystemService
(Context.LAYOUT_
INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate
(R.layout.footer_
layout, null, false);
ListView.addFooterView
(footerView);
```